# Url conf for query params in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django rest framework. I was wondering what will be the url pattern if I want to implement a GET api which has query params as key-value pairs. Something like this:

```
http://example.com/getResource?userid=<userid>&resourceid=<resourceid>
```

Could not find anything like this in django documentation. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: The url looks correct. What's the problem?

Comment: No problem with url, I wanted to know what will be the url pattern for such an api in urls.py file for django rest framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GET requests in Django (in general), you don't need to specify the parameters in the url pattern. In your `urls.py`, you simply write:

```
 url(r'^getResource$', 'app.views.view_function')
```

If your request url is (as in your example):

```
 http://example.com/getResource?userid=<userid>&resourceid=<resourceid>
```

You just get the values in the view function as follows:

```
 userid = request.GET['userid']
 resourceid = request.GET['resourceid']
```

If you're asking specifically about the `django-rest-framework` app, the docs (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart) say your `urls.py` should be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
)
```